# Recommendations to tether a Nikon DSLR to a Windows PC?

Tags: nikon, software, tethering, windows, digital

When I shoot portraits indoors, I'd like the option to tether my Nikon D90 to a Windows computer with the USB cable, both to view the results and help adjust the lighting, but also to be making an instant backup of each shot.

Does anybody have a favorite solution to this?

Comment: Canon's software comes with this bundled in.  Are you sure your camera did not come with a software disk that provides this functionality?  Or have you tried Nikon's, and want an alternative?

Comment: My understanding is this software is not included with the camera. Nikon sells software that includes this feature but it's over $100.

Comment: Not for Windows, but I use Sofortbild on the Mac. It works nicely and it's free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a free program to let you shoot tethered with your Nikon, [this post](http://thephotogeek.com/choosing-nikon-dslr-camera-tethered-shooting-software/) discusses a few of the options.

Comment: I've now used Camera Control from http://www.diyphotobits.com/.  It's OK; downloads a duplicate of the shots and shows a preview.  What I wasn't anticipating is how slow the process would be, relatively speaking.  I am using a somewhat slow laptop, and shooting in a RAW+JPG mode.  It takes a couple of seconds just to download the ~15-20MB of data and render the preview.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the tethering features in [Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 3](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshoplightroom/).

Another option is Nikon's [Camera Control Pro](http://www.nikonusa.com/Find-Your-Nikon/Product/Imaging-Software/25366/Camera-Control-Pro-2.html).

Answer (score 2):

I know that Lightroom 3 Supports camera tethering. It appears to support the D90 according to [this list](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/842/cpsid_84221.html):

**Nikon**

- D3
- D3s
- D3x
- **D90**
- D200
- D300
- D300s
- D700
- D5000

Answer (score 0):

One option is http://www.tetherpro.com/

Answer (score 0):

A **free** option that has just been released in Beta is [Nikontrol 3K](http://nikonrumors.com/2011/01/10/nikontrol-3k-is-a-free-remote-control-pc-software-for-nikon-dslrs.aspx) based on the Nikon SDK. I have not personally tried it however it seems to be very complete from the description.