# How can I have the LiveView of my camera displayed on a TV or Laptop screen?

Tags: nikon, tethering, live-view

If I simply plug in my USB-HDMI cable to a TV or laptop from my camera is there a setting I need to turn On to switch my LCD screen to my TV or computer? My camera is a Nikon D600.

I don't want to control the camera with the TV or laptop. I just want to view the images right after I take them – just as the back of my camera would show.  It seems so simple but I can't find an easy answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to *Intellectual Property* constraints, most notebook or laptop computers as well as desktop models do not have an HDMI port that allows video signals to be brought in via the HDMI port. It is an output only port. This prevents someone from being able to connect a DVD or BlueRay player to their computer and copy protected content. In general the only devices that can accept an HDMI signal and display it are televisions and monitors.

If you are trying to connect your D600 to an HDMI monitor or TV via the camera's USB port using a cable designed for an MHL compliant USB port (such as many mobile phones use to output video to a screen) it will not work since the USB port on your D600 is not MHL compliant. Use a mini-HDMI to HDMI cable to connect the mini-HDMI port on your camera to the HDMI port on a television or monitor.

If you want to shoot with your camera connected to a laptop to view your work as you shoot, you need to use a *tethering* capable [application](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/632/15871) on your computer and connect the D600 to the computer via a mini-USB to USB cable. Even though many tethering applications allow you to control your camera from the computer, most also allow you to retain control using the camera itself.

Comment: I used HDMI to HDMI to a new TV and it worked perfectly! Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if your camera has an HDMI output, then it will display the photos on the TV that it is plugged in to, but I'm not sure what you mean by USB HDMI cable?  USB and HDMI are not the same, there is a technology called MHL that allows HDMI to be output over the same physical port as USB if it has special hardware, however the D600 doesn't have this, it just has a compact HDMI port.  If you are trying to use an MHL adapter with the USB port, it is not going to work and may cause harm to the camera.

You also mention the HDMI connector on your laptop.  Your laptop almost certainly has an HDMI output, it can't be used in both directions.  You can run information out of the laptop to a TV, but you can't run HDMI from your camera in to the laptop.  Attempting to do this may even damage either the camera or your laptop.  If you plug the camera in to a TV via HDMI, then for most cameras, whatever would normally show up on the LCD should be displayed on the TV and the controls on the camera will function as normal.

Comment: @Erin - Just a moment ago I tried this _"If you plug the camera in to a TV via HDMI, then for most cameras, whatever would normally show up on the LCD should be displayed on the TV and the controls on the camera will function as normal."_ and it works as it should on a cheap Sony SLT model. Using the camera, taking photos and seeing it all on TV like in LiveView display; all OK.