# Cameras that can connect to screen

Tags: camera-recommendation, specification

Before I purchase a camera, what specs should I be looking for if I want to make sure it can be easily connected to a TV or computer screen for real-time copy of the camera LCD display?

I have seen that some cameras feature an HDMI port, but is that what I want? Are there other options?

Note: I'm not asking for how to do it with a given model, as suggested by the duplicate question. Instead, I want to know about the generic ways to do this and the various specifications I should be looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have the LiveView of my camera displayed on a TV or Laptop screen?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42785/how-can-i-have-the-liveview-of-my-camera-displayed-on-a-tv-or-laptop-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI would be the best option if need to project the screen live on TV.

**WiFi enabled cameras** are convenient to use **with tablets and phones**.

HDMI may not be the best option to connect to a Laptop since the HDMI ports on the computers are restricted to output. like, it's used only to project the computer screen on projector or TV.

but to **connect to a TV**, **a Mini to normal HDMI converter cable** would be the best option. To view your live screen(Live View mode in Nikon) or to see the pics as soon as you have clicked them, if you are using the viewfinder, this is your option.

**you will not be able to control the cam using HDMI**.

Hope this would help..