# How do I automatically store camera pictures to a PC's hard drive?

Tags: tethering

I just need to be able to either connect a camera (currently the Nikon D5200, but can be changed if necessary) to a PC and then when taking a picture it automatically (without the user doing anything at all) transfers it to a preset location on the computer.

I have looked at the [PhaseOne](https://www.phaseone.com/en/Products/Software/Capture-One-Pro/Highlights.aspx) but it seems too advanced for what I would like to do. I have seen the EyeFi mentioned on here and elsewhere online but I can't find anywhere to purchase the x2 and it looks like the end of life is up next week anyway.

Comment: I know several dozen professional photographers, and none of them has found a solution (they all use cards and manually insert them into the PC). I guess you will have to do it manually... Although it is not rocket science, I wonder why nobody put something on the market.

Comment: Although the question is not strictly a duplicate, this question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/632/recommendations-to-tether-a-nikon-dslr-to-a-windows-pc is has an answer which is relevant.

Comment: @Aganju There are multiple solutions available to do what the question asks. A lot of *somebodies* have put *something* on the market. Most of the DSLR manufacturers include such software with the cameras.

Comment: When I wrote my comment, the question was differently worded - it seemed he asks for a wireless direct connection; for example, you come home and just put the camera on the table, and it starts copying to the PC hard disk without any further trigger. Or maybe it was not and I was dreaming it; anyway, that is what the comment was about.

Comment: What is it about eye-fi or the similar cards like the flashair or Nikon's WU-1a/b that is not suitable doesn't work for you?

Comment: Does it need to be wireless, or is wired OK? I have had success with Lightroom's tethering plug ins in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your level of skill, there are some linux utilities which you can use to script the behaviour of many Pentax DSLRs. pktriggercord is the software you want. (There may be similar for other camera manufacturers - but I don't know of any. pktriggercord apparently has a windows version, but I can't vouch for its utility)

You will need to be able to write basic shell scripts to make use of it to control the camera automatically - however if you have the camera set up to take timed interval shots already (or have an alternative triggering mechanism) - you can simply have it write the shots to a specific place on the computer as they are taken.

Comment: Pktriggercord appears to have limited support for newer Pentax DSLR models.

Comment: The OP has a Nikon...and anyway, pktriggercord has limited to no support for most recent Pentax models.

Comment: @benrudgers "but can be changed if necessary". The answer is appropriate to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [digiCamControl](http://digicamcontrol.com/) software it is free and open source. You can connect camera using usb connection or using nikon WU-1a wireless adapter.

Comment: That's Windows-only.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to do using Canon's *EOS Utility* to shoot tethered with an EOS camera. (Hey, you did say,"...but can be changed...")

- From the main window  click on *Preferences*.
- Select the *Destination Folder* Tab.
- Browse to the desired folder to designate it.
- Select the other options you wish to use, both under the *Destination Folder* tab and under the *Remote Shooting* tab.
- Click *OK* to apply your changes and close the *Preferences* window.
- Click on "Camera settings/Remote shooting".
- Shoot using either the camera controls or the application's onscreen controls.
- To see each shot displayed on the computer screen as it finishes transferring click *Other functions* and select *Quick Preview*.

You probably shouldn't go out and immediately buy a Canon EOS camera, though. Almost all DSLR manufacturers have similar applications available with the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Tethertools has a fairly comprehensive list of software that you would use for tethering.

https://www.tethertools.com/tethering-software/

Typically you have a USB or wi-fi connection between the camera and computer. Software runs on the computer which partially or completely controls the camera and transfers the photos to the computer hard drive.

Details vary by camera, connection, and software.