# Can I tether my Nikon D3200 to Lightroom?

Tags: nikon, lightroom, tethering, nikon-d3200

I have a Nikon D3200. I would like to use Lightroom to tether the camera, but Lightroom is not detecting it. Can I tether my camera to Lightroom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to replicate Nikon D3100 live view on my laptop screen?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/36130/is-there-a-way-to-replicate-nikon-d3100-live-view-on-my-laptop-screen)

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/59842/can-i-live-view-my-nikon-d3200-via-laptop-tablet-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/76053/nikon-d3200-video-tethering-software?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tether Nikon's D3xxx series cameras to Lightroom. Adobe doesn't list any Nikon D3xxx cameras in its [list of tethered cameras supported by Lightroom](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support.html).

This not a fault of Adobe's; rather, Nikon's SDK (which is used by 3rd parties and partners to interact with Nikon's cameras) [does not support D3xxx cameras](https://sdk.nikonimaging.com/apply/).

See these other related Photo.SE questions for more information, and perhaps alternatives (such as TetherTools):

- [Is there a way to replicate Nikon D3100 live view on my laptop screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/36130/is-there-a-way-to-replicate-nikon-d3100-live-view-on-my-laptop-screen)
- [How does digiCamControl support D3100 when no SDK is available?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/80160/how-does-digicamcontrol-support-d3100-when-no-sdk-is-available)
- [Recommendations to tether a Nikon DSLR to a Windows PC?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/632/recommendations-to-tether-a-nikon-dslr-to-a-windows-pc/6776#6776)