# Is Nikon D3200 compatible with external monitor?

Tags: nikon, tethering, nikon-d3200, monitors

Yes I do realize other people asked this question before mostly about android tablets. I am not looking to macgyver something that limits 80% of the camera functionality and most answers focus on that.

I just want to see myself while filming on a small mounted monitor that has decent resolution and latency. Is this available? When I connect my camera with HDMI to a TV any recording is disabled and you can only watch which makes me think camera monitors work the same way?

Also if not how do I make sure next DSLR I buy has that feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Is Nikon D3200 compatible with external monitor?

Not [while recording](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/36143/15871) using Nikon's, Adobe's, or any other applications that use [Nikon's SDK](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/82871/15871).

Not even while using applications, such as [digiCamControl](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80160/15871), that allow *controlling* Nikon D3x00 series cameras via tethering but don't give a Live View image on an external monitor.

> Also if not how do I make sure next DSLR I buy has that feature?

Don't purchase a Nikon D3x00 series camera.

What you are looking for is the ability to do [*tethered*](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering?sort=votes&pageSize=50) shooting with external Live View support. Nikon's D3x00 series of cameras don't offer that level of functionality.

Comment: @AAMon You'd do well to survey the market when setting expectations.  400-500 of any country's dollars gets any manufacturer's bottom-of-the-barrel body, which will have been engineered for cost and isn't going to be packed with features.

Comment: @Blrfl That's true to a point, but at least some other makers do allow tethering and using off camera monitors with even the entry level models. Canon certainly does.

Comment: This is just another example where a feature with virtually no added cost is removed from a lower price-point model for price differentiation (making people who can make pay more, pay more). I didn't buy this model it was a gift now I'll have to resell it lose a few hundred bucks and buy another camera that's going to be identical (I don't use advanced settings) because of this one thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can monitor LIVE!  Go to your camera menu, select [SETTINGS][HDMI]{Device Control] set of [OFF]. Works like a Champ!

Answer (score 0):

I have a D3200.  I just commented about installing and testing Digicam Control on my Windows 10 laptop.  I've also just installed and tested qDslrDashboard with my Android.  Both of these options work like a champ with the D3200.  No issues.  Image as clear as a bell.