# Why my Nikon D3200 does not output HDMI to external monitor?

Tags: nikon-d3200, cables, hdmi

I have a Nikon D3200 DSLR. It has a mini-HDMI output port and when I connect it to either my LG smart TV or my Dell U2415 computer monitor with a mini-HDMI to HDMI adapter, both screens does not show anything coming from the camera.

Am I missing something? My camera's HDMI settings are Auto on resolution and Off on remote control. I put it on Live View mode and I expect the image on the camera screen to be reflected on the external monitor, but it does not. I also did a reset to factory settings but it did not help.

At this point I believe it could be either the adapter, the camera settings or the camera itself that is malfunctioning.

Any ideas on what I can do to eliminate the camera settings as the source of the problem? Otherwise I would need to take the camera to a lab to be examined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is malfunctioning. The Nikon D3x00 series of cameras is not capable of outputting what you desire. The HDMI port seems to be there only to allow reviewing still images and videos *after they are created*.

For more about why you can't use your laptop's HDMI port as an input, please see: [Is there a way to replicate Nikon D3100 live view on my laptop screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/36130/15871)

For more about why you can't use an external monitor in Live View with the D3200, please see: [Is Nikon D3200 compatible with external monitor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96427/15871)

Please also see: [Can I tether my Nikon D3200 to Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82870/15871)

Answer (score -1):

In the case of using the hdmi port on the side of the camera you would need a stand alone capture card for the hdmi port and connect it to the pc that you're using with a USB

Comment: What computer? OP mentions a TV and a monitor. There's a good point behind this answer - HDMI ports and adapters are often uni- rather than bi-directional, so many are only input or output and computers are usually output - but the OP's issue seems to be that they have a camera that provides HDMI output for saved images and they're trying to use it for Live View.

Comment: I am sorry, your answer is simply not addressing the question.