# Nikon D3300 connect to smartphone

Tags: equipment-recommendation, monitors, nikon-d3300

I own a Nikon D3300 and I want to use an external monitor but without spending too much money. D3300 doesn't provide WiFi capability. So, i found out that I can use my phone with an otg cable and actually control the camera via my smartphone. I was able to connect the phone and share photos, but all the apps that were free, like USB camera and helicon remote, didn't display anything and weren't able to be used as shutter buttons. Do you have any suggestions on apps or other cheap alternatives?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to replicate Nikon D3100 live view on my laptop screen?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/36130/15871) and [Why my Nikon D3200 does not output HDMI to external monitor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/130324/15871) and [Is Nikon D3200 compatible with external monitor?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/96427/15871)

Comment: Several of the (at least early) [D5xxx models share this limitation](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/97170/15871) with the (at least early) D3xxx models.